# Use HTML page like PHP/ASP page

Tags: php, html, asp

In ASP and PHP, one can add "?blahblah" to display pages dynamically. I saw somewhere that html page is used in similar way (e.g. index.html?etc.crontab). How is this possible? Is this page really HTML, or PHP/ASP in disguise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a server processed page in disguise. Both asp and php support choosing what file extensions to use